# Programmatically add column names to numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to add column names to a numpy ndarray, then select columns by their names.  But it doesn't work.  I can't tell if the problem occurs when I add the names, or later when I try to call them.

Here's my code.

```
data = np.genfromtxt(csv_file, delimiter=',', dtype=np.float, skip_header=1)

#Add headers
csv_names = [ s.strip('"') for s in file(csv_file,'r').readline().strip().split(',')]
data = data.astype(np.dtype( [(n, 'float64') for n in csv_names] ))
```

Dimension-based diagnostics match what I expect:

```
print len(csv_names)
>> 108
print data.shape
>> (1652, 108)
```

"print data.dtype.names" also returns the expected output.

But when I start calling columns by their field names, screwy things happen.  The "column" is still an array with 108 columns...

```
print data["EDUC"].shape
>> (1652, 108)
```

... and it appears to contain more missing values than there are rows in the data set.

```
print np.sum(np.isnan(data["EDUC"]))
>> 27976
```

Any idea what's going wrong here?  Adding headers should be a trivial operation, but I've been fighting this bug for hours.  Help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that you are thinking in terms of spreadsheet-like arrays, whereas NumPy does use different concepts.

Here is what you must know about NumPy:

1. NumPy arrays only contain elements of a **single type**.
2. If you need spreadsheet-like "columns", this type must be some **tuple-like type**. Such arrays are called Structured Arrays, because their elements are structures (i.e. tuples).

In your case, NumPy would thus take your 2-dimensional regular array and produce a *one*-dimensional array whose type is a 108-element tuple (the spreadsheet array that you are thinking of is 2-dimensional).

These choices were probably made for efficiency reasons: all the elements of an array have the same type and therefore have the same size: they can be accessed, at a low-level, very simply and quickly.

Now, as user545424 showed, there is a simple NumPy answer to what you want to do (`genfromtxt()` accepts a `names` argument with column names).

If you want to convert your array from a regular NumPy ndarray to a structured array, you can do:

```
data.view(dtype=[(n, 'float64') for n in csv_names]).reshape(len(data))
```

(you were close: you used `astype()` instead of `view()`).

You can also check the answers to quite a few Stackoverflow questions, including [Converting a 2D numpy array to a structured array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622850/converting-a-2d-numpy-array-to-a-structured-array) and [how to convert regular numpy array to record array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724711/how-to-convert-regular-numpy-array-to-record-array).

Comment: Thanks -- this helps clear things up conceptually.  But I still have some questions about this particular case.  Here, all of my columns are floats, and I'm going to be doing a lot of matrix multiplication, so I want to keep the 2d-array structure -- no need for structured array.  All I want to do is add field names.  Is that possible?

Comment: NB: genfromtxt imports the csv in numpy's structured tuple format.  I tried everything I could think of to import field names in array format, and nothing worked.

Comment: @Abe: You can still perform matrix multiplications: the `view()` is simply another way to look at the *same* data. So, you can work with both the original data array and the `view()`ed array at the same time (the first array is 2D, the second is 1D and structured).

Comment: @Abe: About your 2nd question: you *cannot* have "field names in (2D) array format". This concept is not valid in NumPy (this is a spreadsheet concept). You want either a non-structured/named-columns 2D array (your `data` array), or a 1D structured/named-columns version of it (the result of `view()` in my answer). I hope this will help clear things up. :)

Comment: @Abe: Technically, I don't want to make things more complicated than they are, but note that you can have a 2D (or n-dimensional) structured array. However, each cell will contain a *tuple*. Example: `arr = zeros((3, 5), dtype=[('x', int), ('y', float)])`, with structure access like `a['x']`, which returns a 2D array of integers.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't know what is going on when you try to add the field names, but I do know that you can build the array you want directly from the file via

```
data = np.genfromtxt(csv_file, delimiter=',', names=True)
```

EDIT:

It seems like adding field names only works when the input is a list of tuples:

```
data = np.array(map(tuple,data), [(n, 'float64') for n in csv_names])
```

Comment: So is it the case that ndarrays can be referenced by field names if they are cast as tuples OR referenced by field id when cast as arrays---but never both?  That seems to be the way it works, but I don't see anything like that in the documentation.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if this is a bug. It's very strange behavior to have the array constructor act differently based on the type of the nested structure you pass in.

Comment: @user545424: You can understand this behavior if you know the principles on which NumPy is based (you can for instance check my answer). In a nutshell: tuple() is a kind of "fundamental type" (like floats), for NumPy (so you get a kind of structured array, when you pass tuples), whereas passing lists or arrays as input means "add another dimension" to the array (you get an array of numbers, typically).